# Group homology of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ with real coefficients

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-groups, group-cohomology

What is known about the group homology of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ with real coefficients and what are strategies to compute it (or at least some groups for low degrees)? Here I want to consider the general linear group with the discrete topology.

There seems to be a lot of research on at first glance more complicated situations (i.e. non-field coefficients and replacing $\mathbb{R}$ by finite fields or more complicated rings), so I was wondering what was known about this seemingly simpler case.

Comment: You are aware of Milnor's theorem "On the homology of Lie groups made discrete"?

Comment: @RyanBudney just to be clear I don't think Milnor's paper solves this problem -- in the rat/real coeffs case he just focuses on showing that the map to group homology with  the usual topology is zero in a range.

Comment: @KevinCasto  I'm not asserting it solves the problem but it provides an enormous amount of  insight.  The question-asker does not make it clear he is aware, so I thought I would point out a result that gives structure.

Comment: @RyanBudney I‘m aware of that. But for the context I have in mind, the fact that the map from cohomology of the topological group to the cohomology of the discrete group being zero is kind of the point.